# Recursive computation of a weighted mean

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion, means

**Background**

Let $u=[u_1,\dots,u_N]'$ be a generic vector, its mean value is defined as
$$
\bar{u}_N \triangleq \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N u_i
$$
in few simple steps one can prove the following recursion
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\bar{u}_k &= \left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)\bar{u}_{k-1}+\frac{1}{k}u_k & k=1,\dots,N\\
\bar{u}_0 &\triangleq 0
\end{aligned}
\qquad(*)
\end{equation}
less trivially, for the more general weighted mean
$$
\bar{u}_N^\lambda \triangleq \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \lambda^{N-i}u_i
$$
where $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ is a given parameter, holds the recursion
$$
\begin{aligned}
\bar{u}_k^\lambda &= \lambda\,\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)\bar{u}_{k-1}^\lambda+\frac{1}{k}u_k & k=1,\dots,N\\
\bar{u}_0^\lambda &\triangleq 0
\end{aligned}
$$
to see why, note that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\bar{u}_{N}^\lambda &= \frac{1}{N}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \lambda^{N-i} u_i+u_N\right)
=\frac{1}{N}\left(\lambda\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \lambda^{(N-1)-i} u_i+u_N\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{N}\left(\lambda(N-1)\frac{1}{N-1} \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \lambda^{(N-1)-i} u_i+u_N\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{N}\left(\lambda(N-1) \bar{u}_{N-1}^\lambda +u_N\right)=\lambda \left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)\bar{u}_{N-1}^\lambda + \frac{1}{N} u_N
\end{aligned}
$$

**Questions**

I'm wondering if it possible to further generalize the previous result to the general case
involving the generic weighted mean
$$
\bar{u}_N^w \triangleq \sum_{i=1}^N w_i u_i
$$
where the weights are normalized, i.e. $\sum_{i=1}^N w_i = 1$ and $w_i\geq 0$. More precisely, I'm wondering if it is possible to find a recursion of the type
$$
\bar{u}_k^w =f(\bar{u}_{k-1}^w, u_k)
$$
If this is not possible in general, I would like to know if, at least, it is possible in the special case where the weights are defined as follows
$$
w_i \triangleq \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{M} & \text{if } i > N-M \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\qquad i=1,\dots,N
$$
with $M$ being a given integer such that $1\leq M\leq N$. Note that for $M\triangleq N$ we have the first recursion $(*)$, while for $M \triangleq 1$ we have
$$
\bar{u}_k^w = u_k \qquad k=1,\dots,N\\
$$

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something, but for $\bar u^w_N$, aren't you just looking for $\bar u_0^w = 0$ and $\bar u_k^w = \bar u_{k-1}^w + w_k u_k$ (e.g. it is unclear to me why is this *not* what you want)? Certainly you should not be able to get a formula without $w_k$ since arbitrary $w_k$ is not knowable from the previous $w_i$ (except $k = N$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my solution. Firstly, denote the unnormalized weights as $\tilde{w}_i \geq 0$, so that the normalized weights are given by
\begin{equation*}
w_i \triangleq \frac{\tilde{w}_i}{W_N} \qquad W_N\triangleq \sum_{i=1}^N \tilde{w}_i
\end{equation*}
then, the weighted mean $\bar{u}_n^w$ is given by the following *couple* of recursions
\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
\bar{u}_k^w &= \left(1-\frac{\tilde{w}_k}{W_k}\right) \bar{u}_{k-1}^w+\frac{\tilde{w}_k}{W_k} u_i\\
\bar{u}_0^w &=0
\end{aligned}
\qquad
\begin{aligned}
W_k &= W_{k-1} + \tilde{w}_k \\
W_0 &= 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Note that, as expected, in the uniform case $\tilde{w}_i = 1$ we get the back $(*)$. The recursion for the normalizer $W_k$ is trivial, while the recursion for the mean is given by the following facts
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\bar{u}_N^w &= \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{\tilde{w}_i}{W_N} u_i =\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \frac{\tilde{w}_i}{W_N} u_i +\frac{\tilde{w}_N}{W_N} u_N\\
&=\frac{W_{N-1}}{W_N} \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \frac{\tilde{w}_i}{W_{N-1}} u_i}_{=\bar{u}_{N-1}^w} +\frac{\tilde{w}_N}{W_N} u_N \\
&=\frac{W_{N}-\tilde{w}_N}{W_N} \bar{u}_{N-1}^w +\frac{\tilde{w}_N}{W_N} u_N \\
&=\left(1-\frac{\tilde{w}_N}{W_N}\right) \bar{u}_{N-1}^w +\frac{\tilde{w}_N}{W_N} u_N 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}